# How to extract the src of an image that is focused by NVDA?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

I am trying to extract the `src` of an `img` that is focused by NVDA (or any screen reader). However, I am unable to get the exact src. this is the code I am using on a particular trigger:

```js
let activeElement = document.activeElement
let URL = activeElement.src
console.log(URL)
```

However, this does not get me the src. At times it prints the whole body of the document. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

try getAttribute() method and pass the attribute name in the argument
example:
`document.getElementById('yourImageId').getAttribute('src')`

Comment: yes, but the difficulty I am facing is how do I correctly select the element that is focused by the screen reader? (i.e. the active element?)

Answer (score 1):

`document.activeElement` will not always point at the focused element. As you have discovered, it sometimes points to the document itself, or its body.

`document.activeElement` can also have some kind of null value in some cases. (e.g. if the browser content is not in focus at all)

So, you'll have to inspect the value of `document.activeElement` first, to see if it is non-null, you can then check the value of its nodeName, to see if it's "IMG", and *then* get the `src`. (nodeName values are always uppercase).

You could listen for `focus` events on the document and ignore those whose [event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets) does not contain an image. I think I would start with this approach.

Some Caveats:

- Images may be implemented in various ways, other than simply an
  `<img>` tag. For example, `<svg>`, `<figure>`, `<picture>`,`<canvas>` amd `<object>` may all represent images. Many of these do not have a `src` attribute.
- Almost anything in the document body can have a background image in CSS, and may therefore appear to be an image.
- Any group of visual elements (including text glyphs and emojis) may represent a single image (semantically speaking), if the group has `role=image`
- The `src` might be a URI rather than a URL (i.e. it might call a server-side process which generates an image on the fly). It might contain a base64-encoded string, representing the image data.

If you are aware of these caveats, it should be possible to do what you intend.